# Discord.py Rewrite: How to get the guild when member joins

Tags: python, discord.py

When a member joins a server, the `on_member_join` function is executed, according to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join):

> Called when a `Member` joins a `Guild`.

Is there a way to get the `Guild` which the member has joined inside the `on_member_join` function?

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild_that_member_joined = ???
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every `Member` object has a `guild` attribute, which is a `Guild` object: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild